# Change TableView text label type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So in my application, I have added [ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift), and I want to use that on my TableView.

So set text on the TableView I can do this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = commentsArray[commentsArray.count - 1 - indexPath.row]
```

or this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = commentsArray[commentsArray.count - 1 - indexPath.row] as? String
```

But how can I change the cell.textLabel.text from UILabel to ActiveLabel?

Comment: It doesn't work like that, an UILabel can't be an ActiveLabel. Look at how they do it in their example, they add an ActiveLabel as a subview: https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift/blob/master/ActiveLabelDemo/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create custom UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html) and insert `ActiveLabel` as a subview. (Note: if you create UITableViewCell in storyboard/XIB make sure you've selected proper class for your label).